# How to add textbox text to label and handling event handler

Tags: c#

I have 4 text boxes and 3 different labels in different panels. my job is when i click any label that 4 text box texts should be assigned to respective label.

my code is as folows

```
string srlnumber;
        string micr;
        string accnumber;
        string tc;
        string compltedata;



private void lblMicr1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        srlnumber = txtSerialnumber.Text;
        micr = txtMicr.Text;
        accnumber = txtAccounno.Text;
        tc = txtTC.Text;
        compltedata = "C" + srlnumber +"C"+ micr +"A"+ accnumber +""+ tc;
        lblMicr1.Text = compltedata;

    }
```

my requirement is when i click label and then if i enter values to the text boxes it has to be assigned to the label. but it is not happening.

can anyone please help me

Comment: what are your labels that is respect to TextBoxes?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that lblMicr1 is the label whose data you want to assign to
>   textbox1.

```
protected void lblMicr1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                lblMicr1.Text = compltedata
                TextBox1.Text = lblMicr1.Text;

            }
```

**Or**

```
 this.MyTextBox.Text = this.MyLabel.Text;
```

> use it , remember to declare label first and then textbox , so that
>   textbox can use label data.

Comment: your tag names are confusing , so i cant understand , the basic solution to add label value to textbox is first declare label and initialize it to some value and then assign its value to textbox . I assume that lblMicr1 is the label whose data you want to assign to textbox1.

Comment: here i am assigning 4 textbox values to 4 separate strings . then i am combining it into single string along with some extra characters. when i click lblmicr label and if i enter values in to textboxes it has to come to label.

Comment: i am out now on smartphone , when i will come home i will edit it and make your code work.